# Problema con calculos en jquery al multiplicar y sumar campos

Tags: php, jquery, yii

Buenas a todos comunidad, mi problema es el siguiente, tengo 4 campos

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 columns" id="multanueva" style="display:none">


<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 row">

    <?php
    echo $form->textFieldGroup($multa_sugerida, 'unidad_tributaria', array(
        'widgetOptions' => array(
            'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'col-sm-5 numeric span5 c_ut conteo',
                'maxlength' => 5, 'placeholder' => 'Unidades tributarias'))));
    ?>


</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 row">
    <?php
    echo $form->textFieldGroup($multa_sugerida, 'valorut', array(
        'widgetOptions' => array(
            'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'col-md-3 numeric ut',
                'maxlength' => 3, 'value' => 177, 'placeholder' => '177 BsF. C/UT', 'readonly' => 'readonly'))));
    ?>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 row">
    <?php
    echo $form->textFieldGroup($multa_sugerida, 'total_unidad_tributaria', array(
        'widgetOptions' => array(
            'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'col-md-3 sumas',
                'readonly' => 'readonly', 'maxlength' => 40, 'placeholder' => 'Total a pagar (BsF.)'))));
    ?>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 row" >
    <?php
    echo $form->textFieldGroup($multa_sugerida, 'unidad_tributaria', array(
        'widgetOptions' => array(
            'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'col-md-3 monto','name'=>'multa_nueva',
                'readonly' => 'readonly', 'maxlength' => 40, 'value' => $montoMulta, 'placeholder' => 'Total a pagar (BsF.)'))));
    ?>
</div>
```

yo hago un jQuery para multiplicar el primero con el segundo y el resultado de este ( el tercero ) lo sumo con  el 4to, eso lo hago aca

```
$(".conteo").keyup(function(){
    var Cant =  $(".c_ut").val();
    var ut =  $(".ut").val();
    var multa_vieja =  $(".monto").val();


    multiplicacion = (Cant * ut);  
    $("#MultasSugeridas_total_unidad_tributaria").val(multiplicacion);
           suma = parseFloat(multiplicacion) + parseFloat(multa_vieja);
   // console.log(suma);return false; //
   $(".monto").val(suma);

});
```

el valor del ultimo campo lo traigo de base de base de datos y lo mando desde un controlador.OK. El detalle es que cuando hago las operaciones, el ultimo campo ( el de la suma y en donde se refleja el resultado del mismo ) suma mas de una vez,y si borro sigue sumando, vale acotar que use el evento change(), hice las operaciones en funciones diferentes, use sentencia if para cuando borrara algún número para que el 4to campo volviera a su valor original, pero NADA . Pero si uso el console.log, si hace las operaciones de manera adecuada e incluso si borro algún número. De verdad no se que hacer . Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda que me puedan dar, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> El error seguramente esta aquí:
>
> ```
> var multa_vieja =  $(".monto").val();
> ```

Si te fijas cuidadosamente:

```
...
var multa_vieja =  $(".monto").val(); // Aquí buscas el valor en `monto`
...
suma = parseFloat(multiplicacion) + parseFloat(multa_vieja);// Aquí lo sumas
...
$(".monto").val(suma); // Aquí lo asignas el nuevo valor a `monto`
```

Si vuelves a ejecutar esto una segunda vez, se va a sumar nuevamente el `monto` anteriormente asignado.

Solución:

```
var multa_vieja =  $(".sumas").val();
```